# How can I get last revision_id of particular event_id?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a revision table like this:

```
id  revision_id  event_id
------------------------
1        1          1
2        2          1
3        1          2
4        2          2
5        3          2
```

I want to get last revision_id for each distinct event_id .
I want MYSQL query to do so.
Can any one guide me??

Comment: Please edit your tags and/or add more information to your question. Which language, database type, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT event_id, max(revision_id)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY event_id
```

See in **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f2e4/1)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(revision_id) , event_id
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY event_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,  max(revision_id),  event_id
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY event_id
```

Comment: Here ID must be in GROUP BY clause or should perform any aggregate on this and this is always unique so will not give expected result